# Closing Stream Error Message UTF 8 Encoding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I've found zero info on this anywhere and hope someone can help me.

I'm trying to send a payment processing string to Authorize.Net using standard .NET streamwriter.  The language I'm using is Visual Basic but even a C# example would be appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
    strPost = "x_FirstName=John&x_LastName=Smith&x_Phone=1234567..ETC..."

    Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = Nothing
    Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll"), HttpWebRequest)
    objRequest.Method = "POST"

    objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length
    objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Try
        myWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream())
        myWriter.Write(strPost)

    Catch e As Exception
        Return e.Message
    Finally
        myWriter.Close()
    End Try
```

If I run this code and type text into the text boxes on the page (which supply the values for the strPost variable), it works fine.

However, if I enter in an international character into a textbox (such as FirstName), or copy/paste someone's name from another web page, it fails with this message:

Server Error in '/' Application.
**Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.**
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.

For example if the letter á is used instead of a, it fails with the error message above.

How do I revise this code to UTF-8 or strip out those characters, etc. and stop getting that message?

Thank you in advance!

-- Chris Lee

Comment: What happens if you convert your string to byte with the proper encoding and write the bytes instead? Something like GetRequestStream().Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)

Comment: Hi the_lotus, forgive me for asking as I'm somewhat new at this, but where/how would I put that in?

Comment: Like this? myWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length) )

Comment: As the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` says: The string should be urlencoded. Use [UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebUtility_UrlEncode_System_String_) before sending the string.

Comment: Try flush() before close : myWriter.Flush()

Comment: jdweng, that worked!!  In adding myWriter.Flush(), I also had to remove the objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length line, but when I did, everything is working now.

jdweng, how do I mark as your answering it so you get points?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the solution using a recommendation from jdweng.  Here's the revised code:

```
    Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = Nothing
    Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    objRequest.Method = "POST"

    objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Try
        myWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream())
        myWriter.Write(strPost)

    Catch e As Exception
        Return e.Message
    Finally
        myWriter.Flush()
        myWriter.Close()
    End Try
```